# file path of '/tmp' in Django Session

Tags: django, session

Right now i am using file based session in django to save data.

`SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.file"`

As per documentation django saves data in `/tmp`, but i dont understand what is actual path of this `/tmp`! Is this a directory in my project or else where?

Comment: This question is totally unclear. `/tmp` *is* a file path, by definitinon. What are you asking?

Comment: No, since it starts with a slash, that is the *root* of the file system (well at least on Unix-based operaating systems).

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah i want to know complete path of this '/tmp', where actually it resides?

Comment: But you misread the documentation, it uses the `tmpfile` construction of the operating system. On a Linux system, that is typically `/tmp`. `/tmp` is a directory that is used for *temporary* files: files with no guarantee that they will exist for a considerable time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misread the documentation, the [documentation [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#using-file-based-sessions) says:

> You might also want to set the `SESSION_FILE_PATH` setting (**which defaults to output from `tempfile.gettempdir()`**, most likely `/tmp`) to control where Django stores session files. Be sure to check that your Web server has permissions to read and write to this location.

If we check the documentation on the [**`tempfile.gettempdir()`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir) we get:

> Return the name of the directory used for temporary files. This
>   defines the default value for the dir argument to all functions in
>   this module.
>
> Python searches a standard list of directories to find one which the
>   calling user can create files in. The list is:
>
> 1. The directory named by the `TMPDIR` environment variable.
> 2. The directory named by the `TEMP` environment variable.
> 3. The directory named by the `TMP` environment variable.
>
> A platform-specific location:
>
> 1. On Windows, the directories `C:\TEMP`, `C:\TMP`, `\TEMP`, and `\TMP`, in that order.
> 2. On all other platforms, the directories `/tmp`, `/var/tmp`, and `/usr/tmp`, in that order.
>
> As a last resort, the current working directory.
>
> The result of this search is cached, see the description of `tempdir`
>   below.

So althought on Unix-based systems (Linux, BSD, Mac OS X, etc.) it will be stored in `/tmp`, it depends on the operating system.

As for Unix-based file systems, if there is a slash (`/`) in the front, that means an *absolute* path, so it is the `tmp` directory in the *root* of the filesystem. For more information on Unix file paths, see [this article [geeksforgeeks]](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/).

If you however set the `SESSION_FILE_PATH` to a specific path, then that path will be used.

Note that temporary files are, well, temporary. Typically you should *not* assume that after a reboot, the files are still there.